# Apt/Aptitude: how to filter packages that are impossible to install?

Tags: apt, aptitude

Especially when running Sid, there are many packages that become non-installable as the dependencies change ABI versions, or the dependencies themselves may have been dropped. It'd be good to know how to filter these packages so that a potential maintainer can check what problematic packages are there on the repo.

So far I came up with:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-cache pkgnames|xargs apt-get -s install\
|sed "/ : /h;/installable/{x;/ .* :/{s/ \(.*\) :.*/\1/;b}};d" | sort
```

It does not recursively mark packages which depend on package "not going to be installed" X, where X is package that is marked because one of the dependecies is "not installable". E.g in the following:

```
foo : Depends on bar but not going to be installed
bar : Depends on baz but not installable
```

`bar` will be marked but `foo` will not. And I shouldn't just mark all packages that has the line "not going to be installed" because it could be bar is a package that exists but breaks another installed package.

Comment: Debian uses a tool like this to filter packages entering testing. Given their habits, the tool is probably packaged for Debian; try looking through `debtags search devel::debian`.

Comment: I can't find any one package that lists such tool. Many packages related to deb, but little about dpkg.

Comment: I suggest asking on the apt (deity) mailing list about this. It is probably straightforward if you are willing to do a little programming using the apt api. This is assuming you are not able to find a tool that already does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know Python, and if you don't today is a good day to start...the documentation for the apt python bindings has a worked example which is relevant, though it may not be a complete solution.

```
apt-get install python-apt python-apt-doc
```

and look at `/usr/share/doc/python-apt-doc/examples/missing-deps.py`. I'm using Debian squeeze.

I just tried it

```
python missing-deps.py
```

and it does produce a small list of packages. My understanding of this script is that it produces a list of packages that are currently uninstallable on Debian main. However, I don't have a Debian unstable installation handy at the moment to test it with.